# align to the center an embedded SWF in sharepoint 2013

Tags: html, css, alignment, embed, sharepoint-2013

i have an embedded .swf file in sharepoint 2013, but it is align to left and i need it in the center, i'm not using text layouts, i prefer to archive this by code because i've see the layouts tend to change in some computers. is there any way to do this?

this is the code i used to embed the file:

```
 <Embed
src="file.swf"TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="736" height="412"
wmode="transparent">
</Embed>
```

thanks a lot for your answers!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want text to be aligned center using css you need to set

```
text-align: center;
```

CSS:

```
.my-embed{
    text-align: center;
}
```